# CMake requires me to manually copy CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to test a project on a cluster where I can't install some libraries in the default locations, so I'm trying to override the default CMake search path with the `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be picked up. I'm having to set the path explicitly with

```
include_directories("." $ENV{CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH})
```

but this seems like a bit of a hack. So I have two questions:

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Is there some cleaner way to add a directory to CMake's include path via an environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is a predefined cmake variable [CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH.html?highlight=cmake_include#cmake-include-path) variable that is a ";-list of directories specifying a search path for the find_file() and find_path() commands." This is not meant to specify the compiler include path.

Secondly, good use of cmake should not involve environment variables. To the extent you can, you should use the conventional cmake `find_package` to configure your build paths. When you need to explicitly add a path to the compiler include search path, then, yes, `include_directories` is what you need. But you should a cmake cache variable rather than environment variable. For details on setting a cache variable, see [this page](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/set.html#set-cache-entry), which says

```
set(<variable> <value>... CACHE <type> <docstring> [FORCE])
```

For your example this becomes:

```
set(MYINCLUDE /usr/local/foo/include CACHE PATH "path to the foo include directory")
include_directories(${MYINCLUDE})
```

Then if you need to override the default `/usr/local/foo/include`, you may specify it with the command line used when invoking cmake; e.g., `cmake -DMYINCLUDE=/home/foo/include .`

Comment: `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` is `:`-separated, not `;`, on Unix. Is it `;` on Windows?

Comment: The ';' list comment is regarding a cmake list variable not the string value. In cmake a variable value is a "list" when it contains embedded ';' characters. So if you specify a list via a command line argument you seperate elements using ';'. For example -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="$HOME/x;/usr/local/foo;/opt/pkg".

Comment: I tried it with `:` and with `;`, and only `:` worked!    `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="/home/me/include1:/home/me/include2" cmake ..`

Comment: ... Actually, I guess it's the difference between passing it on the cmake command line via `-D` and setting an environment variable before calling cmake. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, when specifying on the command line, use the native path separator for the OS (; on windows, : on linux). When setting a cmake list variable either set with space separated values, set(MYLIST1 a b c), or with a ; delimited string, set(MYLIST2 "a;b;c"); both with have the string value "a;b;c".